# Use a method with parameters in a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using an API to retrieve the data.

I created a method in my component which allows to retrieve a boolean to know if a user is banned or not:

```js
methods: {
        getBan(id) {
            HTTP.get(`ban/${id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.bans = response.data.status;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
}
```

In my template I also retrieve all of my users as well as the id of each user:

```html
<li v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user.id">
User id: {{ user.id }}
</li>
```

In my method, I am trying to store the data in an array.

```js
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            bans: []
        };
```

I would like to retrieve the boolean state of my `getBan(id)` method.

I tried several ways, like putting my `getBan(id)` method directly in my user loop, like this:

```html
<span>Status ban: {{ getBan(user.id) }}</span>
```

Obviously it can't work since in my method I store my data in a "`Bans`" array.

I wanted to know how I could suddenly get the data from my `getBan(id)` method ?

Comment: What does `bans & users` having? you need to write example with data and What does API response return?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it something in code, maybe in one of hooks like `created` or `mounted`. And afterwards you can just use `user` to show his props somehow in your template.

```
data: {
  return {
     user: {}
  }
},
mounted: {
  const { data: user } = await HTTP.get(`user/${id}`)
  this.user = user
}
```

```
<div>{{ user.id }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I understood what you did. However I want to know how to fill my ʻid` parameter directly from my template or maybe I'm wrong and have to do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

You juste have a little error :

You forgot a "s"

```
<div>{{ getUserById(user.id) }}</div>


<div>{{ getUserById(users.id) }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div>{{ getUserById(users.id) }}</div>
   ....


   async gerUserById(id) {
      const { data } = await HTTP.get(`user/${id}`)
      this.users = data
      return this.users;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get a "[object Promise]".Guess I have to go through a Promise?

Comment: `await HTTP.get(user/${id})` is equal as doing `HTTP.get(user/${id}).then(response =>`, you need to check if `HTTP.get(user/${id})` is returning a promisifyed data or not and change it accordingly

Comment: I am receiving data but it loops endlessly in each user. Do you know why ?

Comment: you need to add more details in the question, to see what's going on, we can't assume what you're doing right. Add more details, then let's see where it's gone wrong

Comment: Still not suffice, you need put the example with data